# BN254 specification?

Tags: elliptic-curves, standards, bn254

Sorry for asking another question but is BN254 specification standardized? I am using two different implementations one python another solidity and the prime field $F_p,F_{p^2}$ and the the group order $q$ are defined differently in those two versions.

Solidity version:

$p = 21888242871839275222246405745257275088696311157297823662689037894645226208583$, $q=21888242871839275222246405745257275088548364400416034343698204186575808495617$

Python version:

$p = 16798108731015832284940804142231733909889187121439069848933715426072753864723$
$q = 16798108731015832284940804142231733909759579603404752749028378864165570215949$

Is there some issue with this? Why am I seeing two different definitions both called BN254.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a [draft RFC on pairing friendly curves](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-pairing-friendly-curves-11.html) where it is explicitly listed as being in ["4.1.2. Cryptographic Libraries"](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-pairing-friendly-curves-11.html#name-cryptographic-libraries) rather than in "4.1.1. International Standards". So no, it doesn't seem to be standardized. The latest revision of this draft RFC seems to be on 2022-11-06. I don't think it is under active development as it refers to "ISO/IEC 15946-5: Cryptographic techniques based on elliptic curves
Part 5: Elliptic curve generation" as being under development while the [2022 version](https://www.iso.org/standard/80241.html) has been published. I'd argue that this reference should be updated or at least indicate a date when the status was observed if it were ever to be adopted as an RFC:

> On the other hand, the parameters may be revised in future versions since ISO/IEC 15946-5 is currently under development.

Note that this draft RFC, as well as other resources found point out that the effective security of this curve only reaches 100 bits, pointing towards ["Challenges with Assessing the Impact of NFS Advances on the
Security of Pairing-based Cryptography"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1102.pdf). That's not weak enough to be directly attacked, but it falls short of the 128 bits of security that the cryptographic community strives for. This is also the reason why the RFC mentions but does not endorse it. More precisely, the draft seems to be aimed at standardizing existing pairing friendly curves that *do* meet the 128 and 256 bit security. The inferred strength of 100 bits makes any kind of endorsement of the curve in a national or international cryptographic standard *extremely* unlikely.

It also mentions that the BN254 curve is also known as BN128 alluding to its *intended* security strength; that naming was probably not a good idea in hindsight.

Comment: Yes it seems so. It looks like Ethereum uses pre-compiled pairing function for a curve that matches with the Solidity version. And I found the specification matching python version https://neuromancer.sk/std/bn/bn254 here.

Comment: About the security, I am aware of limitations however I am yet to find something that I can use with Ethereum with better security. It does not help that Ethereum's primitive int type is at most 256 bits. It is for the research purposes only, not to use for secure production.

Comment: Now that's something I cannot help you with; I'd wager that [ethereum.se] would be a better place to ask which algorithms to use in their blockchain framework. And I'm not arguing in any direction, but a security strength of ~100 bits (claims of 96 to 110 if my search abilities have been successful) will just not do for inclusion in a state or international standard about cryptography.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes (and community): I wish I knew if _"ISO/IEC 15946-5 is currently under development"_ refers to the paywalled version of [ISO/IEC 15946-5:2022 (edition 3)](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/en/#iso:std:iso-iec:15946:-5:ed-3:v1:en), or to a later one actually under development